# How to insert a row into another table using last inserted ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having two table on my `SQL` server `GamerName` and `GamerValues`, I want that, when I `insert` a new row on `GamerName`

```
 GamerName

    ╔════╦═════════╦
    ║ ID ║  Name   ║
    ╠════╬═════════╬
    ║  1 ║ Jeff    ║
    ║  2 ║ Geoff   ║
    ║  3 ║ Jarrod  ║
    ║  4 ║ Joel Sp ║
    ╚════╩═════════╩
```

So, with the last `inserted` ID on the table `GamerName`, the values should be filled on `GamerValues`

```
 GamerValues

╔════╦══════════════╦════════╗
║ ID ║  GamerID     ║ Score  ║
╠════╬══════════════╬════════╣
║  1 ║ 1            ║ 5636   ║
║  2 ║ 2            ║  148   ║
║  3 ║ 3            ║  101   ║
║  4 ║ 4            ║  959   ║
╚════╩══════════════╩════════╝
```

Is it possible to do it with a single query?

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/different-between-scope-identity-ident-current-and-identit/

Comment: Search for `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER`

Comment: You can use `after insert Trigger` to do this.

Comment: You can make stored procedure that has gamer name as input, once you insert into GamerName, just use magic table `inserted` to take ID of it and then just do another insert into GameValues

Comment: Use `store procedure` to `INSERT` new records for `GamerName`. In that procedure, after `INSERT` a new record to `GamerName`, just `INSERT` another new record to `GamerValues`. IMO you should avoid using `trigger`.

Comment: @Yugandhar looks like every line in that link was copied verbatim from the MSDN documentation. It's also *not* necessary since at least 2008. The OUTPUT clause will return the last value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a trigger or any of the `@@IDENTITY`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` functions. All of them have restrictions and none of them can deal with values that aren't produced by an `IDENTITY` constraint. None of them can deal with multiple insertions either.

You can use the [OUTPUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause of `INSERT` to copy newly inserted values into another table or a table variable.

OUTPUT is also available for UPDATE and DELETE. You can retrieve the new/modified columns with the `inserted.` and `deleted.` prefixes

For these tables :

```
create table #GamerName 
(
    ID int IDENTITY primary key, 
    Name nvarchar(20) not null
);
create table #GamerValues(
    ID int IDENTITY primary key,
    GamerID int not null,
    Score int not null
);
```

You can insert new records in `#GamerName` and copy the generated ID to `#GamerValues` with :

```
INSERT INTO #GamerName (Name)
OUTPUT inserted.ID,0 into #GamerValues(GamerID,Score)
VALUES 
('Jeff'),
('Geoff'),
('Jarrod'),
```

New values appear in the `inserted` virtual table. OUTPUT is also availa

A new line will be created for each of the gamers in GamerValues. Let's modify the default score with :

```
UPDATE #GamerValues 
SET Score=100
```

The table will look like :

```
ID  GamerID Score
1   1       100
2   2       100
3   3       100
```

Adding another gamer with

```
insert into #GamerName (Name)
output inserted.ID,0 into #GamerValues(GamerID,Score)
Values 
('Joel sp')
```

Will result in a new line with a Score of 0

```
ID  GamerID Score
1   1       100
2   2       100
3   3       100
4   4       0
```

Comment: Can you put more than one OUTPUT statement inside? This answer was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You should manage this with a stored procedure. You can concentrate any additional logic you need when creating a new gamer this way (for example, checking if already exists).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateGamer
    @Name VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 'gamer name already exists' FROM GamerName AS G WHERE G.Name = @Name)
    BEGIN

        RAISERROR('Gamer name already used!', 16, 1)
        RETURN

    END

    INSERT INTO GamerName (
        Name)
    VALUES
        (@Name)

    DECLARE @GamerID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO GamerValues (
        GamerID,
        Score)
    SELECT
        GamerID = @GamerID,
        Score = 0

END
```

You can ensure the uniqueness of the gamer name with a `UNIQUE` constraint, I'm just using the `EXISTS` to show how you can put additional logic in your SP.

Comment: @@IDENTITY is not the right thing to use, if someone has put a trigger on the table you would get an incorrect value, use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: Nice. This is the way I would do it too. But I would also pass the score value in a @Score parameter with default value 0 to the procedure and use it in the INSERT query for the GamerValues table.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a trigger to this for you.

```
CREATE TRIGGER newTrigger ON GamerName
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO GamerValues
        (GamerID)
    SELECT
        'ID'
        FROM inserted

GO
```

Btw the score variable should be set 0 by default since you don't have a value when a new user is created. Unless if you do.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you have an identity column in Gamername Table you can use

```
INSERT INTO GamerName (Name)VALUES
('Joel Sp');


INSERT INTO GamerValues (GamerID,Score)
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() ,0 score;
```

If you just need the last column inserted and assuming the gamer id in gamername table are sequential then you can simply use

```
INSERT INTO GamerValues (GamerID,Score)
select max(id),0 score from gamername;
```

If Nothing Satisfies your condition then **TRIGGER** is the best Option