# INSERT in SQL where foreign key is auto-generated in another table

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have a table 1 with an auto-generated primary key in SQL Server. I have a second table 2 where the auto-generated value from table 1 is a foreign key in table 2.

How can I write a query where I can `INSERT` into table 2, including the auto-generated value from table 1.

Preferably this would also work in a stored procedure.

Generate scripts:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POSTADRESSE](
    [AdresseID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [GateNavn] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [GateNR] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [PostNR] [int] NULL,
    [PostSted] [varchar](30) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [XPKPOSTADRESSE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [AdresseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[KUNDE](
    [TelefonNR] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [AdresseID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Epost] [varchar](320) NULL,
    [Fornavn] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Etternavn] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Passord] [varchar](69) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [XPKKUNDE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TelefonNR] ASC,
    [AdresseID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

This is what I've tried:

```sql
INSERT INTO POSTADRESSE(GateNavn, GateNR, PostNR, PostSted)
VALUES ('Storgt', 3, 3901, 'Porsgrunn')


INSERT INTO KUNDE(TelefonNR, AdresseID, Epost, Fornavn, Etternavn, Passord) 
VALUES (
    47843329,
    (SELECT POSTADRESSE.AdresseID FROM POSTADRESSE WHERE POSTADRESSE.GateNavn = 'Storgt'),
    'hej@hotmail.se', 
    'Anton', 
    'Johanson', 
    '123abc'
    );
```

Comment: If you are always dealing with single rows, then use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`; if multiple then the `OUTPUT` clause (to `INSERT` the data into a table variable).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a row into another table using last inserted ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50406121/how-to-insert-a-row-into-another-table-using-last-inserted-id)

Comment: Thank you @Larnu. `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @VaBraAnton see this answer will help.

```
Declare @Identity as int
INSERT INTO POSTADRESSE(GateNavn, GateNR, PostNR, PostSted)
VALUES ('Storgt', 3, 3901, 'Porsgrunn')

Select @Identity=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
INSERT INTO KUNDE(TelefonNR, AdresseID, Epost, Fornavn, Etternavn, Passord) 
VALUES (
    47843329,
    @Identity,
    'hej@hotmail.se', 
    'Anton', 
    'Johanson', 
    '123abc'
    );
```

see screen shot

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com]

Comment: Thank you for the clarity and example code!