# Create record in related table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Projects` and an `Addresses` table. Each project can have one address.

Is there a way to write a query so that when an address is created its address ID (which is autogenerated) gets returned and inserted into the appropriate row in the `Projects` table?

Thanks very much

[diagram of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJzMJ.png)

I've tried creating the address ID, and then searching in the address table for that record and then manually add the id field to the appropriate project row. However that solution does not work.

Comment: And what is `the appropriate row` in the projects table?

Comment: It would be the Project for which the address is being added. I thought it would make sense to have a seperate addresses table and then when I am creating a new row on the project table I can then create a new row in the address table at the same time

Comment: So each project can have one address, but can each address have more than one project? What process is auto-generating the addressID in Addresses table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [INSERT in SQL where foreign key is auto-generated in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74097753/insert-in-sql-where-foreign-key-is-auto-generated-in-another-table)

Comment: Yes exactly the though process was that different tables (like projects, customers, etc) can have an address field but the database would only have one address  table

Comment: Yes that link shared helps

Comment: Patrick Hurst's answer is better than the one linked by Peter B (Use `OUTPUT`).
Also, you might want to look into triggers (depending on if the `Projects` insert needs to be automated too).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the `OUTPUT` clause:

```
/* Mock up the addresses table */
DECLARE @Addresses TABLE (AddressID INT IDENTITY, Address1 NVARCHAR(200));

DECLARE @Output TABLE (AddressID INT, ProjectName NVARCHAR(200))

INSERT INTO @Addresses (Address1) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.AddressID INTO @Output (AddressID)
VALUES ('123 Any Lane')

SELECT *
  FROM @Output
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Thanks very much for this. How would it work if the Row in the Projects table already exists and the row in the Addresses table is new. (so an update command would need to happen with the project ID of the row I want to add the address ID into ?

Comment: No differently, really.
What you are going to want to do in that instance though, is pass along the project ID as part of the process. Your sproc might accept a `User defined table type` or individual  parameters, which will needto include the ID of the project you want to update, as well as the new address. You'd use these in concert with the `OUTPUT` to make sure you update the correct project, and tie it to the new address.